# Question About CCMenuItemToggle

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I create a Toggle menu with this code :

```
[CCMenuItemFont setFontName:@"STHeitiJ-Light"];
    [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:40];
    CCMenuItemFont *toggleON = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"I'm On!"];
    CCMenuItemFont *toggleOFF = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"I'm Off!"];
    CCMenuItemToggle *item3 = [CCMenuItemToggle itemWithTarget:self selector:@selector(menuItem3Touched) items:toggleON , toggleOFF , nil];

-(void) menuItem3Touched {

NSLog (@"test 3");

}
```

now what can I recognize these items to do some action , I mean when toggle is ON do something and when is OFF do something else ?

thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found it ! I was completely confused ! :D

```
- (void) menuItem3Touched :(id) sender  {

    switch (item3.selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"on");
            break;
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"oFF");
        break;
        }
    }
```